# Syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that removes all the .jpg's that end in an odd number. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start\n"
for f in *.jpg
do
  fname=$(basename "$f")
  echo "fname is $fname\n"
  fname="${filename%.*}"
  echo "fname is $fname\n"
  if[$((fname %  2)) -eq 1 ] then
    echo "removing $fname\n"
    rm $f
  fi
done
```

When I run it it outputs start and then says "syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'"

When I had then on the line after if it said "syntax error near unexpected token 'then'"

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

As well as having `then` on a new line, you also need a space before and after the `[`, which is a special symbol in BASH.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start\n"
for f in *.jpg
do
  fname=$(basename "$f")
  echo "fname is $fname\n"
  fname="${filename%.*}"
  echo "fname is $fname\n"
  if [ $((fname %  2)) -eq 1 ]
  then
    echo "removing $fname\n"
    rm "$f"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Its still giving me "syntax error near unexpected token 'then'"

Comment: The code I've posted runs without any errors on my own systems. I can only recreate the error you're citing by removing the space between the `if` and the `[` character. Make sure all the spaces I've described are in place.

Comment: You have forgot to quote ``"$f"``

Comment: I was only focusing on the syntax error in question, but fair point, I've edited the code to include these quotes.

Comment: It should not become a problem because filenames are expected to have a number + .jpg in them, but correct quoting is highly recommended anyway. Still I don't like your if expression, there's no point to use test command there. So I am between giving this answer -1 or nothing at all...

Comment: You can also precede the `then` with a semicolon.

Comment: This specific error is due to the 'then' not being on a new line. It's also worth noting that putting a semicollon (; after

Comment: So I'm coming back to this more than 6 years later, and I still see the poor code style in this answer. Stackoverflow is rather depressing sometimes.

Answer (score 39):

Use Notepad ++ and use the option to Convert the file to UNIX format.
That should solve this problem.

Comment: This solved my problem. Was moving script from a windows machine to linux.

Comment: This worked well for me, I created a sh on windows using EditPlus, and use cygwin to run it, converting to UNIX format is very useful.

Comment: Also helped me after writing a script on Windows and trying to run it on a Mac. I did the conversion using Sublime Text (**View** > **Line Endings** > **Unix**).

Comment: Editing file on Windows, running on WSL. This helped!

Comment: Notepad++ -> Config -> NewDocument -> Unix(LF)  and create new document. this works for me

Comment: I fixed it from: Notepad ++ -> Edit -> EOL conversion -> Unix

Answer (score 13):

"Then" is a command in bash, thus it needs a ";" or  a newline before it.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start\n"
for f in *.jpg
do
  fname=$(basename "$f")
  echo "fname is $fname\n"
  fname="${filename%.*}"
  echo "fname is $fname\n"
  if [$[fname%2] -eq 1 ]
  then
    echo "removing $fname\n"
    rm $f
  fi
done
```

Comment: As I said, When I had then on the line after if it said "syntax error near unexpected token 'then'"

Comment: It had another  cause, this script  doesn't do this. But there is another problem,  $(( … )) tries to execute "fname % 2", and this is not what you want. I corrected this problem,  too.

Answer (score 9):

The first problem with your script is that you have to put a space after the `[`.
Type `type [` to see what is really happening. It should tell you that `[` is an alias to `test` command, so `[ ]` in bash is not some special syntax for conditionals, it is just a command on its own. What you should prefer in bash is `[[ ]]`. This common pitfall is greatly explained [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D) and [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bbar.3D.22.24foo.22.5D.3B_then_...).

Another problem is that you didn't quote `"$f"` which might become a problem later. This is explained [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target)

You can use arithmetic expressions in `if`, so you don't have to use `[ ]` or `[[ ]]` at all in some cases. More info [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr)

Also there's no need to use `\n` in every `echo`, because `echo` places newlines by default. If you want TWO newlines to appear, then use `echo -e 'start\n'` or `echo $'start\n'` . This `$''` syntax is explained [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings)

To make it completely perfect you should place `--` before arbitrary filenames, otherwise `rm` might treat it as a parameter if the file name starts with dashes. This is explained [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Filenames_with_leading_dashes).

So here's your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start"
for f in *.jpg
do
    fname="${f##*/}"
    echo "fname is $fname"
    if (( fname % 2 == 1 )); then
        echo "removing $fname"
        rm -- "$f"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 5):

The original question has long since been answered, but since this was the first Google result for "unexpected token fi", I'm posting the mistake I made that I have not seen mentioned yet.

I copy-pasted some code from a different question which looked something like:

```bash
REPLY="Hello"
if [[ $REPLY =~ "Server is up" ]]; then
    # echo "Something"
fi
```

The problem with the above is that the only line of code in the conditional block is commented out, and **an empty conditional block is invalid syntax in bash**.

Uncommenting the echo statement resolves the syntax error. Alternatively, if I intended a no-op block, I could have written `:` as my only line of code in the block:

```bash
REPLY="Hello"
if [[ $REPLY =~ "Server is up" ]]; then
    :
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

@sagar's answer solved my problem (Save file to UNIX format), please note that if you are using VSCode, you can select the file's end of line sequence (LF or CRLF) at the bottom right.

Also see this [CRLF vs LF](https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/crlf-vs-lf-normalizing-line-endings-in-git/#:%7E:text=Whereas%20Windows%20follows%20the%20original,the%20era%20of%20the%20typewriter.) if you would like to understand the why. Common problem when you are working on different OS.

Comment: This was my issue. I just used backspace to clear everything and retyped them manually and its fixed.